# Redshift JDBC connection fails authentication when user password with # character in it

Tags: java, jdbc, amazon-redshift

I've run into a problem with JDBC connections to Redshift that I can't quite solve.  Using the example given in the documentation I can easily connect to a Redshift cluster when a user has a plain password, but when a user has a password with a # character in it I get an authentication failure.  I am able to connect to the cluster using SQL Workbench/J using both sets of credentials.  When I use the following, no connection problem.

```
        DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(60);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("user", "johndoe");
        props.setProperty("password", "superSecret");
        props.setProperty("tcpKeepAlive", "true");

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:redshift://xxxxxxx.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev", props);
```

When I use the following,

```
        DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(60);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("user", "johndoehash");
        props.setProperty("password", "superDouble#Secret");
        props.setProperty("tcpKeepAlive", "true");

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:redshift://xxxxxxx.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev", props);
```

I get the an authentication error

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: password authentication failed for user "johndoehash";
  at com.amazon.redshift.client.messages.inbound.ErrorResponse.toErrorException(ErrorResponse.java:1830)
  at com.amazon.redshift.client.InboundDataHandler.read(InboundDataHandler.java:454)
  at com.amazon.support.channels.AbstractSocketChannel.readCallback(Unknown Source)
  at com.amazon.support.channels.PlainSocketChannel.read(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: password authentication failed for user "johndoehash";
```

I can log onto the cluster with both accounts using SQL Workbench/J but for some reason I can't connect through my application.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try assigning the password to a variable and then passing that password in the setproperty.

Comment: Yes I've done that and gotten same results.  Thinking that perhaps the # is causing some sort of problems because of its use in http  (?? just a guess)  I've tried URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF8") with no difference in effect.

Comment: Sorry I dont have exact solution, I am not informed on java, just taking guesses, but whatever helps, right? Did you try using CHR(35)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment.  I don't know if this will solve your issue or not.  But try this:

props.setProperty("password", "superDouble& #35;Secret");

Without the space between "&" and "#35;"

Alternatively

props.setProperty("password", "superDouble%23Secret");

Comment: I've tried various encoding and escapes on the password and it did not have any effect.  On a lark I tried yours too, and sadly it made no difference.  I'm starting to suspect it lies in the dependencies of the driver.  I'm going to explore the differences in dependencies between my application and others where a password with # can be successfully used.

Answer (score 0):

This is really odd but if I use a year old version of Java 8 with my application

```
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

The problem goes away ...  Go figure.